# ASP:NET MVC: return file : internet explorer 11 new tab?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download

Ie9, Chrome and Firefox can open new tab with the code bellow, but Ie11 force the download instead of open new tab.

```
byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(contentDetailInfo.ContentFilePath);
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + contentDetailInfo.ContentFileName);
return File(fileBytes, contentDetailInfo.ContentFileMimeType);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + contentDetailInfo.ContentFileName +"\"")
```

More: [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1)